# Returning results for jQueryUI autocomplete from mySQL database

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm attempting to create an autocomplete field with a remote source pulling data from an SQL database:

```
$("#venuename").autocomplete({
        source: function(req, add){  
                $.getJSON("../autocomplete/venues.php?callback=?", req, function(data) {                        
                        var suggestions = [];
                        $.each(data, function(i, val){
                        suggestions.push(val.name);
                });
                add(suggestions);
        });
}
});
```

venues.php:

```
require '../../includes/connect.php';

$param = $_GET["term"];


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM venue_details WHERE venueName REGEXP '^$param'");


for ($x = 0, $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); $x < $numrows; $x++) {  
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);  

    $venues[$x] = array("venueName" => $row["venueName"]);  
}


$response = $_GET["callback"] . "(" . json_encode($venues) . ")";  
echo $response;
```

I've been racking my brain for hours on why this isn't working, and looked through numerous online resources for answers, but found nothing to fix my issues. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `$.getJSON("../autcomplete/venues.php?callback=?", {term:req}, function(`

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified - The autocomplete simply does not function. Nothing at all happens when typing into the field. I've attempted `{term:req}` but to no avail.

Comment: have you tried logging what you get as `req`? try `console.log(req.term);` or `alert(req.term);`

Comment: `req` contains the string I enter into the field, changing as I enter a new character/remove a character.

Comment: I'd recommend using Firebug if you aren't already. It nicely shows the results of requests made, and any js errors that happen...

Comment: It looks like you are making a JSONP request. Is this working correctly? Use the developer tools in your browser to see if the request is succeeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery autocomplete needs a `label` and/or `value` field returned:

> The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be inserted into the input element after the user selected something from the menu. If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, eg. if you provide only value-properties, the value will also be used as the label. [jquery ui docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

There are a number of ways to solve this but if you are using `jsonp` you could try [jquery ui's example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

You could try changing this:

```
$venues[$x] = array("venueName" => $row["venueName"]);
```

to this:

```
$venues[$x] = array("label" => $row["venueName"]);
```

It will use the `label` value for both the dropdown choice and the `value` attribute of the dropdown.

Comment: This is exactly where I was going wrong, thanks for the help!